# Not able to get access to a function is nested calls (React)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```js
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import Login from './login';
import ChatScreen from './chatscreen'

export default class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn :false
        }
    }

    getLoginStatus(status){
        this.setState({isLoggedIn:status});
    }

    showScreen(){
      
        if(this.state.isLoggedIn)
            return (
             <ChatScreen checkStatus={(status)=>{this.getLoginStatus(status)}}/>)
        else if(this.state.isLoggedIn===false)
        return (
            <Login checkStatus={(status)=>{this.getLoginStatus(status)}} />
            )
            
            
    }
   
 render(){
        return this.showScreen()
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

So, My probelem is this.
I have used google's signin api to detect whether user has signed in or not.
When he has signed in he sees his main page with a signout button.

When he clicks on the signout button his instance is grabbed and signOut function is called on that instance and the user is signed out.

Now, in order to go back to the login screen, I have defined the state of parent component and passed a function call back to each of the login and logged in screen from where when they call the function using `this.props.checkStatus()`. The state of parent component is changed and the parent is re-rendered showing login screen or the logged in screen based on its state.

I got it right for the login screen.
But when I am signing the user out I am not able to call the callback using `this.props` as I am calling it inside nested callbacks.

Please provide me a way to call this.props.checkstatus(false) as soon as the singOut() is called.

```js
import React,{ Component } from 'react';


export default class App extends Component{


 componentDidMount(){
     document.getElementById("signOut").addEventListener("click",this.logOut.bind(this));
    
}

    logOut(status){
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
            console.log("outlog");
             this.props.checkStatus(false);
          });
         
     }
    

 render(){
        return <button id="signOut">out</button>
        
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

**Solution**
watch this video to understand how this works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQ4__W9nELc

what I used was ecmascript 6 feature or binded the this context like this.

**Using ES6 Arrow function**

```js
logOut(){
        
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(()=>{
            this.props.checkStatus(false);
        });
        
     }
```

or using **BIND**

```js
logOut(){
        
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function(){
            this.props.checkStatus(false);
        }.bind(this));
        
     }
```

**warning**

avoid saving your context like

```js
var that = this;
```

Comment: Where is your checkStatus method ?

Comment: it is in the parent component I have updated the question see thr

Comment: The exact question is unclear. So is the answer. There is both an accepted answer and an answer added to the question that is different.

Comment: The question deals with the basic understanding of context passing in javascript. I was just trying to know what "this" holds in different cases. I came to know about binding this while passing a function as parameter which the arrow function does by default. So both the answers are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        document.getElementById("signOut").addEventListener("click", this.logOut.bind(this));
    }

    logOut(status) {
        // Supposing your checkStatus method is in props
        var me = this; //Saving Context of your Component here
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function() {
            // this here points to the callback method after signOut
            // has performed its task. So this will point to that
            // context. 
            console.log("outlog");
            me.props.checkStatus(false); // Here we used the context saved 
            //above so we can access the required method.
        });

    }

    render() {
        return <button id = "signOut" > out < /button>
    }
}
```

Just save the context of your App before calling the `checkStatus`.

Comment: I am pretty new to this. So can you tell me how?

Comment: Actually its not about react js, but about how Javascript works. You are trying to access `this` in different function. In your case, that was callback function of signOut api, so `this` will have context of the callback method after signOut is done, which in case is different from your React Component Context, which I suppose you are confused about.

Comment: Got the answer about understanding how this is passed in a function here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQ4__W9nELc

Comment: Hope you got it right about context. Hope it solved your problem then so you can mark it a solution ! Also I have added comments inside the solution for your clarity.

Comment: I have added the solution below to help others do check it. It's much efficient and correct.

Comment: Yeah, Using Arrow operators always saves you from lot of context troubles. ES6 is a Savior.